# Armazenar um array de select em uma variavel js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso percorrer vários select e armazenar o seu `value` em um array com jQuery, mas não consigo. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes criar uma coleção com `$('select')` e depois usar `.map()` para gerar uma array, e `.get()` para converter de uma coleção jQuery para uma array nativa.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```
var values = $('select').get().map(function(select){
    return select.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi bem o que quer mas veja se lhe ajuda:

```
var array = new Array();
$('select').each(function(index, el) {
  array.push($(el).val());
});
console.log(array);
```

Se quiser pegar somente os options selecionados:

```
var array = new Array();
$('select option:selected').each(function(index, el) {
  array.push($(el).val());
});
console.log(array);
```